# Using where in condition in pg-promise to check for columns that has a value found in an array of values

Tags: sql, node.js, arrays, postgresql, where-clause

I want to update a table and set "withdrawn" to true where column iid has a value found in a given computed array.

```
let iids = data.map(el => el.iid);
// data is an object array with iid prop of type string

db.many('UPDATE bonuses SET withdrawn = $1 WHERE iid IN ($2) AND sponsor = $3 RETURNING iid', [true, iids, email]); 
//email is a preset string
```

When I tried this, I got the following error:

> operator does not exist: character varying = text[]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: There is [csv filter](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#csv-filter) for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if `iid` belongs to the array parameter, you want to use `ANY` rather than `IN`:

```
UPDATE bonuses 
SET withdrawn = $1 
WHERE iid = ANY($2) AND sponsor = $3 
RETURNING iid
```